# New activity with ImageView from GridView

Tags: android

I'm trying to show an image in an ImageView in a new activity, but  I have problems. The new activity is open and I can see the path to the image in a toast meassage, but there is still no image visible! What could be wrong?

Part of the MainActivity class:

```
       gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("image", imagePath);

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

FullActivityClass:

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    //int id = i.getExtras().getInt("image");
    //ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    String imageId = i.getExtras().getString("image");

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageId));
    //imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, "" + imageId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

***FullActivity.java***

```
Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageId);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Let me know if it works for you..

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hmm, but the imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); should be in the FullActivityClass!? Why won't it work with out the BitmapFactory?

Comment: As your code shows that you want to set inside FullyActivity.

Comment: It's working, but when I return to the GridView the ID of the images seems to change and not showing the image i selected?